# Proving $\mathbb{E}(u)\mathbb{E}(v)\leq\mathbb{E}(uv)$

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> Let $u,v:\;\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be increasing functions and $X$ a
>   random variable in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that:
>   $$\mathbb{E}[u(X)]\mathbb{E}[v(X)]\leq\mathbb{E}[u(X)v(X)]$$

**Attempt:** let $X,Y$ be independent identically distributed random variables. WLOG $X\geq Y$. Then $u(X)\geq u(Y)$ and $v(X)\geq v(Y)$. In particular:

$$\mathbb{E}\Big[\big(u(X)-u(Y)\big)\big(v(X)-v(Y)\big)\Big]\geq0 $$ $$\iff \mathbb{E}\big[u(X)v(X)\big]+\mathbb{E}\big[u(Y)v(Y)\big]-\mathbb{E}\big[u(X)\big]\mathbb{E}\big[v(Y)\big]-\mathbb{E}\big[u(Y)\big]\mathbb{E}\big[v(X)\big]\geq 0$$ $$\iff2\mathbb{E}\big[u(X)v(X)\big]-2\mathbb{E}\big[u(X)]\mathbb{E}\big[v(X)\big]\geq 0$$

Which is equivalent to what we need.

Is this correct? I am unsure whether I am aloud to say WLOG $X\geq Y$.

Comment: You can't just substitute $X$ for $Y$. You had assumed them to be independent. Further, $X \geq Y$ doesn't make much sense when they are random variables. It _does_ make sense if you qualify that the relation holds _almost surely_.

Comment: @Nitish I performed the substitution because they are identically distributed, so $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\mathbb{E}[f(Y)]$, no? For the second comment, yes I wasn't sure about that. Can what I have done be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key-step (which does not need the faulty step explained in the comments) is the almost sure inequality
$$
\left(u(X)-u(Y)\right)\cdot\left(v(X)-v(Y)\right)\geqslant0,
$$
which may be seen to hold on the events $[X\gt Y]$ and $[X=Y]$ and $[X\lt Y]$.